# Rows with NULL correspond to row above it in Postgres: how to aggregate those rows?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that looks like this in Postgres:

| company_name | product_sku | amount_purchased |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Great Company 1 | SKU55 | 6 |
| null | SKU77 | 13 |
| null | SKU88 | 3 |
| Great Company 2 | SKU55 | 21 |
| null | SKU33 | 7 |

Assume that every `null` in the `company_name` column corresponds to the company above that row. So in the case of `SKU77` it belongs to `Great Company 1`.

How could I write a query that tells me what the best selling `product_sku` values are for each company?

Comment: In a SQL table there are no rows "above" or "below" anything; there's no intrinsic order. You have to order by some criterion explicitly. Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [PostgreSQL LAG and LEAD functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/functions-window.html).

However, Relational Database Management Systems don't have any intrinsic order to rows in a table, unless you provide one by adding a key column.  Even then, the relationship between rows the way you describe it should be discretely managed by linking child and parent rows via a shared key column.

So, for instance, you could have this table design:

```
CREATE TABLE products
(
      product_id         int            not null  //this is the parent key
    , company            varchar(100)   null
    , sku                varchar(100)   not null
    , parent_product_id  int            null      //this links to other rows product_id value
);
```

Inserting your rows would be something like:

```
INSERT INTO products (product_id, company, sku, parent_product_id)
VALUES 
      (1, 'Great Company 1', 'SKU55', NULL)
    , (2, NULL, 'SKU66', 1)
    , (3, NULL, 'SKU77', 1)
    , (4, 'Great Company 2', 'SKU55', NULL)
    , (5, NULL, 'SKU66', 4);
```

Then you could write a query that shows the company names along with SKUs via something like this:

```
SELECT p.company
    , p.sku
    , c.sku
FROM products p
    LEFT JOIN products c ON p.product_id = c.parent_product_id
```